# spring integration test fail to load context "Another resource already exists with name dataSource"

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jta, spring-test, atomikos

I am using test annotation introduced in spring-boot 1.4.3 for my integration tests

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceIT { }
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching), test context is cached and reused to speed up integration tests.  This behavior is what I want since it takes significant amount of time to initialize application context. My failsafe plugin is configured with

```
<forkCount>1</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
```

to allow integration tests to run in the same process to take advantage of application context caching.

Recently, I wrote a integration test used @MockBean annotation to mock behavior for some beans.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AnotherServiceIT {
  @MockBean
  SomeService service1
}
```

While the test runs fine on it's own, when running through maven verify, multiple integration tests fails with the error message

> javax.naming.NamingException: Another resource already exists with
>   name dataSource - pick a different name

If I skip this particular test with JUnit @Ignore annotation, everything goes back to normal.

This behavior seems to indicate that using @MockBean changes the caching behavior, and each test attempts to create its own datasource.  I should also mention that I am using an **AtomikosDataSourceBean** created through **XADataSourceAutoConfiguration**.

How can I overcome this issue so my integration test can still use cached context and use `@MockBean` at the same time?

Comment: Could it be this issue with spring-boot? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7174

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the issue.  I am using spring-boot 1.4.3 and that issue should have been resolved.  I will do some debugging to find out if it is that.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, does SomeService relate to your Datasource in any way?

Because your context is cached and @MockBean does the following:

> used to add mocks to a Spring ApplicationContext ... Any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the mock,

and

> If there is more than one bean of the requested type, qualifier metadata must be specified at field level:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 public class ExampleTests {

 @MockBean
 @Qualifier("example")
 private ExampleService service;
```

**Edit:**

So if your SomeService is an implementation of a DataSource try adding a Qualifier.  If SomeService has a DataSource in it, and you need to access some methods in it, you could try to use @Mock and specify the any objects that need to be returned either through their own mock or autowire.

```
@Mock
SomeService someService;

@Mock
SomeDependency mockDependency;

@Autowired
OtherDependency realDependency;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    doReturn(mockDependency).when(someService).getSomeDependency();
    doReturn(realDependency).when(someService).getOtherDependency();
}
```